# Disabling HealtCheck for specific DataSources in Spring Actuator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datasource, spring-boot-actuator

i have issue with disabling specific DataSources in Spring Actuator. I currently have task in my application to implement Spring Actuator, but need Actuator to ignore/disable for some features in app(Health Indicator mainly). Application is built from other mini apps. Any suggestions or instructions how to start it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disable the default datasources health indicator

```
management.health.db.enabled=false
```

and customise the your required data source with DataSourceHealthIndicator

example:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource requiredDataSource;

@Bean
public DataSourceHealthIndicator requiredDataSourceHealthIndicator() {
    return new DataSourceHealthIndicator(requiredDataSource);
}
```

Comment: I solved problem long ago like this, but thank you anyway for answering.

Comment: @JozoSkoko If you figured out the the query you've asked on SO. Please try to update the post with your findings and solution so that others will not waste time under impression that it is still open and perceive this as rude. Happy learning!

Comment: If you create more than one `@Bean DataSourceHealthIndicator`, don't forget to give them distinct names and, preferably, annotate the main one with `@Primary`.

Answer (score 3):

An important point to prevent the [Health](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.2.13.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/jdbc/DataSourceHealthIndicator.java) check system becomes fully none-functional due to **infinite loop** for waiting for database connection is to configure the `connectionTimeout` and `validationTimeout` in datasource config.

In the case that we using HikariCP as connection pool provider, with respect to the case in hand the implementation will look like below,

```html
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    ...
    config.setInitializationFailTimeout(1000);
    config.setConnectionTimeout(1500);
    config.setValidationTimeout(1500);
        
    ...
        
    return new HikariDataSource(config).unwrap(DataSource.class)
```

```html
@Bean
public DataSourceHealthIndicator dataSourceHealthIndicator(){
    ...
    return new DataSourceHealthIndicator(dataSource, "SELECT 1");
}
```

```html
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomHealth implements HealthIndicator {

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        ...
        return Health.status(healthIndicator.health().getStatus()).build();
    }

    private final DataSourceHealthIndicator healthIndicator;
}
```

And as **Bhushan Uniyal** stated you can disable the actuator default DataSourceHealthIndicator in your property files

```html
YML

management:
  health:
    db:
      enabled: false
      
Properties

management.health.db.enabled: false
```

Comment: In spring boot you can simply specify the timeouts using properties, no need to redeclare and manually configure the datasource. It might even make things worse as it will disable parts of the auto configuration and binding.

Comment: Thanks for the comment ! The whole semantic of configuring the datasource in application aware level will not effect or make things worse ! many datasource proxies are orthogonally deactivate the Auto configuration of datasource creation . I appreciate if you avoid to tell too generalized form and be specific specially in the case in hand. @M.Deinum